# how can i get the right fields into a group and sum using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of objects (Debtors) in this structure

```
 public class DebtorDto 
    {
        public string OutstandingBalance { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

which looks like

```
OUTSTANDINGBALANCE  NAME    COMPANY  INVOICENUMBER
1500                Debtor1 comp1    1235      
1600                Debtor1 comp3    1236      
150                 Debtor2 comp1    1234      
1700                Debtor2 comp4    1237      
15000               Debtor1 comp1    1238      
150                 Debtor1 comp3    1239      
500                 Debtor4 comp1    1274      
1500                Debtor3 comp3    1634      
500                 Debtor3 comp1    1334
```

what I would like to do is present the total amount (Sum) owed by each debtor

for example (please note the total amounts below are not accurate I've just made them up but they need to total the above amounts)

```
Debtor1  31050
Debtor2  3050
Debtor3  1050
Debtor4  41050
```

what I have so far is

```
var query = from e in _allDebtors.GroupBy(x => x.Company)
                .Select(y => y.Sum(z => decimal.Parse(z.OutstandingBalance))))))
```

this actually gives me the correct amounts like below but I don't know how to get the name of the debtor in there as well?

```
31050
3050
1050
41050
```

Comment: Do you want totals by Debtor (shown in your results) or by company (shown in your working example)?  You suggest by debtor originally, then by company later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your return value in the `Select`:

```
var query = _allDebtors.GroupBy(x => x.Company)
            .Select(y => new { Company=y.Key, Total=y.Sum(z => decimal.Parse(z.OutstandingBalance)) });
```

Note that this is by *company* - if you want it by debtor, it would be:

```
var query = _allDebtors.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(y => new { Name=y.Key, Total=y.Sum(z => decimal.Parse(z.OutstandingBalance)) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from e in _allDebtors.GroupBy(x => x.Company)
                                 .Select(y => new {
                                              Name = y.Key,
                                              Sum = y.Sum(z => decimal.Parse(z.OutstandingBalance))
                                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query = from e in _allDebtors.GroupBy(x => x.Company)
            .Select(y => new {Name = y.Key, TotalAmount = y
                                                 .Sum(z => 
                                                  decimal.Parse(z.OutstandingBalance))});
```